# Will hashing a UUID with CRC32 be always unqiue?

Tags: hash, uuid, crc32

For example, I have a UUID 3f107c44-336c-409b-b6d8-889d552a5339, if I hash it with a CRC32, can I ensure none of the hash of UUID will collapse?

=========

Reason I wanted to ask this is because I was uncertain if I am correct.

What I really wanted to do is to generate a unique id based on an existing unique id.

Comment: Think of how many bits in input, how many bits on output. If latter smaller than former, collisions exist definitely.

Comment: IMHO: since the UUID (=Universal Unique Identifier) IS unique, the CRC just a hash function, the result will be unique too

Comment: @Radinator Mathematics doesn't care about opinions.

Comment: I've not heard of a good reason to hash a UUID value; just use the [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID) value (a 128-bit value, already virtually unique). Rephrase your Question to explain your purpose or goal.

Comment: @BasilBourque That was just something I am curious and I am unsure about, almost certain it won't work.   I just wanted to generate a shorter unique ID base on an existing unique ID we already have.

Comment: Remember that the hex string you quote in your Question is *not* a UUID. Those 36 characters are a textual representation of the UUID for the convenience of human readers. A UUID is actually 128-bit value. Yes, you can devise shorter IDs but they will not be virtually unique like a UUID. UUIDs are standardized, well-defined, well-understood, recognizable visibly in that canonical 36-character hex string presentation, and are increasingly common including in databases such as Postgres and H2. Don't fix what ain’t broke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. A UUID represents a 128-bit value. A CRC-32 is only 32 bits. So at *best* you have a mapping of any one CRC-32 value to 2<sup>96</sup> (79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,336) different UUID values.

Comment: I see :( How about if I use an increment counter from 0? Then hash CRC32 on each of the value? W ill it be unique?

Comment: Why hash it? Yes, if you just count up the UUIDs you encounter as you encounter them, and you don't encounter more than 2^32 of them, then you have mapped just those into 32 bits. However that would be of no value for a hash table, since you can't then find the hash value from just the UUID.

Comment: I was just trying to find a way to generate a unique id that is shorter than UUID, GUID etc. So what I meant was not count up from the UUID, I wanted to count up from really an integer 0, 1, 2..N, then hash etc integer.

Comment: I got that. Yes, it would be unique. It would also be useless without a table mapping the UUIDs to the integers.